# Slick - How to use Pause on Hover?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, slick.js

I'm working on an AngularJS app, I want to use Slick to have a carousel to display images.

Simplified, my HTML looks like this:

```
<slick pauseOnHover="false"  autoplay="true" autoplaySpeed="1000" dots="true" touch-move="false" slides-to-show="3" speed="400" slides-to-scroll="1" ng-if="main.CarouselReady" infinite="true" class="slickCarousel">
    <div ng-repeat="img in main.myImages">
        <img src="{{img.src}}" />
    </div>
</slick>
```

I have buttons linked to my controller.js's functions to pause / resume the slick carousel, this is working fine.

The problem is that the carousel is not autoplaying when my mouse is over (hover ) the images section. The setting "pauseOnHover" is set to false so I don't understand why it's not autoplaying when my mouse is in...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pauseOnHover` should be written `pause-on-hover` when using the attribute notation:

```
<slick pause-on-hover="false" ...>
    ...
</slick>
```

Answer (score 21):

User `pauseOnHover:false` on slick config

for example:

```
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  pauseOnHover:false
});
```

Comment: He is asking for exactly the opposite of what you said.

Comment: I was wrong with the syntax of the setting , I was using "pauseOnHover" on the html tag , instead of "pause-on-hover" ( thx Mistalis ), I didnt get that "pauseOnHover" is for JS use only

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I was trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.slideshow').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      pauseOnFocus: false,
    });
```

Comment: add some explanation to this answer

Answer (score -1):

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.slick-slider').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 0,
      speed: 3000,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      cssEase: 'linear'
      });
    });
```

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 136px;
  line-height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 2%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-slider {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
     <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slick-slider">
  <li><h3>1</h3></li>
  <li><h3>2</h3></li>
  <li><h3>3</h3></li> 
  <li><h3>4</h3></li> 
  <li><h3>5</h3></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).